# How to generate one time password in meteor js

Tags: meteor

**I have seen `pascoul:otp` but their is no documentation present.Is their any method to generate otp in meteorjs?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the [Random](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/random) package by Meteor. A random string of numbers and letters is the best password you can have.

Comment: That code needs to be changed after few seconds similar to otp. How that can be done with Random?

Comment: This really depends on your use case and how you want to implement it, but you could use some kind of Cron package ([like this](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cron)). Then create a cron that calls a function to generate a new password, and update the database with it as well as show it to the user. It really just depends on how you want to do it, but you could set functions to a cron to allow them to automatically change.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  var otp = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7); 
  Session.set("OTP", otp);
}, 60*1000);
```

This function will generate for you a code every 60 seconds using Random and set it in the session to compare it when you want.. I hope it help you ^^